# CSS: Adjusting Div containers using margin

Tags: html, css

I've created a website with 2 white sidebar widgets, a grey article box and some colored buttons. Currently the Widget and circle items get positioned using the CSS attribute `left:175px;` for `#mw-panel`, meanwhile `#right-navigation li a` gets placed using `right: 30em;`.

Unfortunately this only looks best on my specific 1080p screen. If the browser window gets resized the widget and button items begin to overlap the main article.

I tried to turn `left: 175px;` into `margin-right: 20px;`, so that the widgets keep a constant distance of 20px between the article. After trying this, my white widgets got placed to the left edge of my browser window. I then tried to change display:absolute; to something else, but I was unsucessful.

What do I have to change in my code in order to get the same result as in the picture?

[image]

```css
#right-navigation li a {
font-size: 14px;
color: white;
text-shadow: 4px 4px 15px #000;
display: block;
padding-left: 60px;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 2);
transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 2);
    width: 250px;
}

#right-navigation li, #right-navigation li:after {
    -webkit-transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
    transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}

#right-navigation li:after {
content:'';
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 50%;
left: 20px;
top: 20px;
}


#right-navigation li:hover:after {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}

#right-navigation li:hover > li {
transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#right-navigation li:hover a {
    opacity: 1;
    padding-left: 75px;
}

#right-navigation li{
border-radius: 50%;
margin-top: 10px;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .11), 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .22);
transition: 0.2s opacity;
}

#left-navigation {
position: absolute;
}

#right-navigation{
position:absolute;
right: 30em;
top: 250px;
}

.content .entry {
    background-color: #6b6b6b;
}

#mw-panel,#p-personal {
padding: 1em;
background: #fff;
border-radius: 10px;
position: absolute;
left: 175px;
width: 240px;
}

#ca-view{
top: 120px;
background:url('data:image/png;base64,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') no-repeat center,radial-gradient(#00FFFF, #00878E);}

#ca-ve-edit{
top: 180px;
background:url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAABMklEQVQ4T53USytFURgG4IeBOz+GUiISUQYmLhGSKPlDp0SSlCQJuY0MlZl/Yqbc+7SPdqd9Oees6Vr72d+7vrVWi+ZHKypYxiqug2pp0gtsHxvJ9+9YwFWzYD+e0JYqKND5RsE+DOARszirQV8bAQN7QFT3Fy8DrdQL9ibYUO2epdA7zNUD9uAewzUN/G8ExvCMtzIwsPjzSM5pCHQQL9X5IrAbtxgtOFq72MFPGdiVYBElb+xhO43lHexO3GC8ADvAVi2WBQYWV2iiADvEJr6z1qT3sCPBJguwo+S6ZWLpCgO7xFQBdoz1vMrSTWlPsOkC7ARr+Cp7TCJyNGCmYOEpVurBqpH/z1AGGpc/3rvSytKR88BzLOGzLGZ6PiJngRdYbBTLixzdjufpo5HKqmt/AYr2Pul4ZEE5AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC') no-repeat center, radial-gradient(yellow, #BD9D01);
}

#ca-edit,#ca-viewsource{
top: 240px;
background:url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAAtklEQVRIS92VwQ3CMAxFXyeBURgFJilMAqMwCmxSWYqlUuzEapJWai+92P/Z34kz0PkbOutzfMAZ+BRszMbkLLonYf17nGycB5CkEXgAEYAbawFUXCq+Aa+CRVfgmWL+CloC5uKR6pXt5s0BUXEZ6hs4AV/gkg6Cma+AWnG3EwG0EjchUYBnizX/n4IjFq0WF3dKQ64Sl/Y2PabWkJpftCUkctmya2W3ZaeddF3XTV7T4z+Z1TZNfeFJGe4QW0kAAAAASUVORK5CYII=') no-repeat center, radial-gradient(orange, #B75D00);
}

.site-inner,
.wrap{margin:0 auto;max-width:1200px;}

.site-inner{clear:both;padding-top:40px;}


body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#434343, #282828);
    color: #555;
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body class="full-width-content">

  <link rel="stylesheet" id="child-theme-css" href="https://vocaloid.de/wp-content/themes/Vuturize/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
  <div id="mw-panel">

    <div class="portal" role="navigation" id='p-navigation' aria-labelledby='p-navigation-label'>
      <h3 id='p-navigation-label'>Box1</h3>
      TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="site-inner">
    <div class="content-sidebar-wrap">

      <main class="content">
        <article id="content" class="page type-page entry">
          <h1>Demo</h1>
          <div id="bodyContent" class="mw-body-content">
            <div id="jump-to-nav" class="mw-jump">
              <a href="#mw-head">Navigation</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </main>
    </div>

    <div id="mw-head">
      <div id="p-personal" role="navigation" class="" aria-labelledby="p-personal-label">
        <h3 id="p-personal-label">Box2</h3>
        TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</div>

      <div id="right-navigation">
        <div id="p-views" role="navigation" class="vectorTabs" aria-labelledby="p-views-label">
          <h3 id="p-views-label">Ansichten</h3>
          <ul>
            <li id="ca-view" class="selected">
            </li>
            <li id="ca-ve-edit">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please provide the rest of your CSS and or make a fiddle/codepen. The easiest way for anyone to help you would be to replicate the problem.

Comment: @theblindprophet There is already the full CSS code embedded. Consciously, I hadn't add the CSS. If I had, you would have to override the code. Inspecting the element might work, from my opinion.. Or is it due to the problem solving to others? Well I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

add this class to .site-inner to align container center of screen.

```css
.site-inner{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: I applied your annotations to the correct class, but it did not seem to work. I tried adding my mentioned "margin" attributes, but I was unable to make a 20px gap between the widgets and the article.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `px` pixel specific sizes, rather use `%` or `em` sizes.
You can also have CSS `@media` query selectors to set the basis for `em` size by setting the `body{font-size:**px}` (where * is a number based on a fraction of the current display/window size).

This will set the basis of your responsive layout and your contents will scale accordingly.

If you need a highly scalable solution, rather try building your content in SVG, and have the SVG element have `min-width` and `min-height` properties on the SVG element root which will prevent things from getting too small.

Here's an example of the SVG explanation:

```
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    version="1.1"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    viewBox="0 0 1920 1080"
    style="display:block; min-width:640px; min-height:360px">

    ... The rest of your code here ...

</svg>
```

The above will scale very well, as you can see, the resolution is based on your current resolution, but will scale perfectly and keep proportions on smaller (or bigger) resolutions/monitors.

The only drawback is that you will have to do everything in SVG, which is not a bad thing, but may be an issue if the requirement states otherwise.
The advantages are great though, because you can build your interactive components using an SVG editor, like "Inkscape" (free), then save, and view your mock-ups in a web-browser -which of coarse saves a lot of time as opposed to coding *everything* by hand.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Making it responsive might be an option I should think about later on, but first I should get the margins working.

I am also thinking that using % or em won't be the proper solution to my problem.. Even if I would apply your recommendations, they will only work for ´ĺeft´ and not ´margin-left´.

I hope you noticed you noticed the difference of both: Currently it checks the left & right edge, but instead it should check the .site-inner div container and make a  20px gap